# Can you optimise the Responsive Images Wordpress creates?

Tags: wordpress

I'm analyzing my site using Google PageSpeed Insights. It says "Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data." I've definitely done that as I'm uploading images that have been through https://tinypng.com/.

I *think* it's WordPress causing the issue by generating various responsive images as the warning is related to a filename `-1024x525.png` which isn't the name of the file I uploaded.

Is this the automatically generated WordPress responsive images? If so, is there a way to optimize them? Google seems to think I can save ~30% which would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your suspicion is quite right. The optimizations made by tinypng will not translate into the resized versions WP is creating. They do have a Plugin (aptly named "TinyPNG") for WordPress that can take care of the optimization for you when you upload images (and also fix those you already have).

That said, you should take Google's suggestions with a grain of salt. They usually recommend a lower quality for JPGs that some people find unacceptable. Find the right balance between optimization and quality, don't try too hard to make Google's algorithm 100% happy if you'll make the stay less satisfactory for your visitors in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the "grain of salt" point. I think that makes this the most useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin also which can you use in your site
https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Here is optional things which you can use it.. https://wordpress.org/plugins/imagify